# Swift @IBInspectable properties in a framework not displayed to Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, interface-builder

I'm trying to make a framework of a custom UIViewController using `@IBInspectable` to edit its properties in Interface Builder.

```
public class BWWalkthroughPageViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBInspectable public var speed: CGPoint = CGPointZero
    @IBInspectable public var speedVariance: CGPoint = CGPointZero
    @IBInspectable public var animationType: String = ""
    @IBInspectable public var animateAlpha: Bool = false
}
```

If the framework source code is in a sample app project, the properties come up to Attribute Inspector as shown in the image below,

[image: IBInspectable]

but if I add the built framework to my app project, the properties are not displayed in the inspector.

Is it possible to show the inspectable properties in a built framework to Interface Builder? If possible, how to?

Here is the framework source code, which is forked from a non-framework project.
https://github.com/yoichitgy/BWWalkthrough/tree/support-carthage

Comment: @IBDesignable class BWWalkthroughPageViewController

Comment: Thanks. I tried @IBDesignable but it didn't work.

Comment: It should though. Sometimes it helps if you close the window or change the panel view. Force IB to redraw its view. Also look in the user defined runtime attributes. It's just a nicer interface to that dictionary. If you ever delete an IBInspectable and it's complaining, then that's because it's still defined inside that dictionary

Comment: Thank you for updating. I tried closing the panel, and also restarted Xcode, but still Attribute Inspector doesn't come out. In contrast, User Defined Runtime Attributes panel works. If the source code is in the project, Inspector panel and User Defined Runtime Attributes panel are connected, and one update the other. But if only the built framework is added, only User Defined Runtime Attributes panel works. I checked BWWalkthrough.framework/Headers/BWWalkthrough-Swift.h, and I found no IBInspectable information is written out though IBOutlet and IBAction are written in the header file.

Comment: There is a recent wwdc video where to showcase this. Have you seen that one?
So far it has been hit and miss for me as well. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Maybe it only works well for new projects?

Comment: I didn't watch the wwdc video (here just fyi: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/). I'll make my own UI framework soon from scratch. I'll update whether I can solve the problem here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue. It works inside my framework, but not when I import it to an app.

Comment: @gpojd, still it does not work unless the framework project is included in the target app project. Check `FrameworkName-Swift.h` header file in your built framework. No information about `IBInspectable` is exported there.

Answer (score 3):

### Creating framework

Create default framework and add there your swift files.

[image]

Then set your swift files as public.

[image]

After that copy your framework and add it to your project folder

[image]

### Use the framework

Add the framework in your project

[image]

Create new viewController in your storyboard and set viewController's class which is located in your framework

[image]

Thats all. You will see your your properties in the storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

The reason the attributes won't show up in Interface Builder in your app but do in your framework is because your framework isn't a target of your app. The easiest way to ensure that it is included is to use [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org), it'll handle everything nicely for you and the setup is relatively easy.

A side note: `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` really don't have anything to do with each other. With `IBInspectable`, you can expose a limited amount of property types to Interface Builder or a Storyboard (things like `NSNumber`, `Bool`, `UIColor`, etc). `IBDesignable` however is used to live render your views in a nib or storyboard. They're very handy to use together i.e. changing properties for your inspectable attributes and seeing your view rendered.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` are available if you use Cocoapods because the dynamic framework project is added to your workspace. How do you set up your project with [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage)? It usually adds a reference to the built framework.

Comment: I've only used carthage once or twice, it's much less automated than cocoapods but gives you greater flexibility with the built process. With Carthage, you have to manually drag the dependencies in so when you do, just make sure that your application is checked off as a target of the framework you're adding and that you add your frameworks in 'Link Binaries with Library` in the Build Settings section

Comment: Yes, a project is setup with Carthage as you told, and `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable ` do not work because only the already built framework is added to the project. I appreciate your answer but this question is in case using the built framework. I think it is good to support both Cocoapods and Carthage.